# Sort and group objects alphabetically by the first letter from an array in Angular?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, sorting

How can I sort and group objects alphabetically by the first letter from an array in angular? I have seen the example to do this Sort and group objects alphabetically  in [Javascript](https://www.cluemediator.com/sort-and-group-objects-alphabetically-by-the-first-letter-from-an-array-in-javascript) and  the exact answer and output json i am looking in Angular.

As of now My api json is like [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnvhnn-nijmv7?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html)

Expexted api json would like [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnvhnn-swvrba?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.ts)

I have tried this but i am unable to found the solution in angular.

real Json:

```
employees = [
  { name: "Abigail", age: "25" },
  { name: "Axle", age: "29" },
  { name: "Brianna", age: "25" },
  { name: "Brooklyn", age: "23" },
  { name: "Camila", age: "24" },
  { name: "Charlotte", age: "28" },
  { name: "David", age: "22" }
];
```

expecting json after sort and group objects alphabetically by the first letter from an array would like:

```
[
  {
    "alphabet": "A",
    "record": [
      { "name": "Abigail", "age": "25" },
      { "name": "Axle", "age": "29" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "alphabet": "B",
    "record": [
      { "name": "Brianna", "age": "25" },
      { "name": "Brooklyn", "age": "23" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "alphabet": "C",
    "record": [
      { "name": "Camila", "age": "24" },
      { "name": "Charlotte", "age": "28" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "alphabet": "D", "record": [
      { "name": "David", "age": "22" }
    ]
  }
]
```

expected output like:

```
A
Abigail
Axle
B
Brianna
Brooklyn
C
Camila
Charlotte
D
David
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a Typescript specific sorting method. TS is a superset of Javascript. So all valid JS should also be valid TS.

Comment: thanks for the comment if possible please update the stacblitz for the better understanding. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, there is no Typescript specific way to sort and group the data. You could the JS [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group the objects to your requirement.

Try the following

```js
const employees = [ { name: "Abigail", age: "25" }, { name: "Axle", age: "29" }, { name: "Brianna", age: "25" }, { name: "Brooklyn", age: "23" }, { name: "Camila", age: "24" }, { name: "Charlotte", age: "28" }, { name: "David", age: "22" } ];

const output = employees
  .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const idx = acc.findIndex(e => e.alphabet === curr.name[0]);
    if (idx === -1) {
      acc.push({ alphabet: curr.name[0], record: [curr] });
    }
    else {
      acc[idx].record.push(curr); 
      acc[idx].record.sort((r1, r2) => r1.name > r2.name ? 1 : -1);
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .sort((e1, e2) => e1.alphabet > e2.alphabet ? 1 : -1);

console.log(output);
```

It would look like following in the Stackblitz.

```js
export class ExpansionOverviewExample {
  @ViewChild(MatAccordion, { static: false }) accordion: MatAccordion;

  employees = [
    { name: "Brianna", age: "25" },
    { name: "Axle", age: "29" },
    { name: "David", age: "22" },
    { name: "Brooklyn", age: "23" },
    { name: "Camila", age: "24" },
    { name: "Abigail", age: "25" },
    { name: "Charlotte", age: "28" }
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.employees = this.employees
      .reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const idx = acc.findIndex(e => e.alphabet === curr.name[0]);
        if (idx === -1) {
          acc.push({ alphabet: curr.name[0], record: [curr] });
        } else {
          acc[idx].record.push(curr);
          acc[idx].record.sort((r1, r2) => (r1.name > r2.name ? 1 : -1));
        }
        return acc;
      }, [])
      .sort((e1, e2) => (e1.alphabet > e2.alphabet ? 1 : -1));
  }
}
```

You could also use safe navigation operator `?.` in the template so you don't get any `undefined` errors before the `reduce` is complete.

```html
<div *ngFor="let mani of employees">
    <div>
        <p>{{mani?.alphabet}}</p>
        <p *ngFor="let group of mani?.record"> {{ group?.name }}</p>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've updated your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnvhnn-b449b4?file=app/expansion-overview-example.ts)